# Ошибка отрисовки QPainter поверх QMediaPlayer

Tags: c++, qt, astra-linux, qmediaplayer

Хочу сделать простенький виджет - видеопроигрыватель с кнопками поверх самого видео (например как в ютубе). Собрал простейшую сцену для видео плеера по этому [посту](https://forum.qt.io/topic/1024/paint-over-qvideowidget/9). Отрисовка работает. Добавил в том же переопределённом paintEvent'е картинку кнопки "старт" по середине экрана. И она отрисовывается, но к сожалению только в статике.

Прсле переопределения mouseEnterEvent() и mouseLeaveEvent() столкнулся с проблемой, что когда останавливаешь видео, QPainer просто перестаёт работать и не отрисовывает ничего, пока снова не включишь видео, хотя сами эти методы, судя по отладке, работают. Почему так происходит? И как можно нормально отрисовать кнопки QPainter'ом поверх QMediaPlayer?
Так же ещё есть неприятный момент, что весь оверлей не отрисовывается в областях виджета, где нет самого видео (масштабирую видео в переопределённом resizeEvent'е где вызываю метод fitInView()), соответственно видео масштабируется по размерам виджета с сохранением своих пропорций и остаются пустые области в виджете, на которых отрисовка так же невозможна.

Примечания: С QT знаком всего 1.5 месяца и не знаю всей внутренней кухни, пользуюсь версией 5.11.0 и пишу под astra-linux. А так же пишу с телефона - прошу прощения за разного рода ошибки и отсутствие полного кода. Код сделан прямо как в посте, за исключением пары самостоятельно переопределённых методов, которые я описал выше.

Comment: для того чтобы уведомить виджет об изменениях, то есть чтобы ему было послан `QPaintEvent` необходимо выполнить `QWidget::update`, в вашем случае очевидно, что update выполняет проигрыватель, когда работает

Comment: @PavelGridin, методы Update() стоят в каждом переопределённом методе. Сначала вызывается сопутствующий метод родительского класса, далее моя логика, после, в конце, вызываю update() (и repaint() иногда). Но такое ощущение, что когда видео на паузе - виджет целиком стопориться, хотя все ивенты работают (добавил qDebug() в каждый и они выводятся в консоль)

Answer (score 0):

Всё до банальности просто. Необходимо лишь было добавить метод обновления для самой сцены (QGraphicsScene::update()), а не вызывать метод update() переопределённого мною класса QGraphicsView внутри paintEvent'a и все проблемы решились.